# Getting other field values of a line with MIN/MAX values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, max, aggregate, min

Here is a sample of my data and what I would like to see:

```
JOB    OPSEQ    OPCOMPLETE   OPCODE

100     1        yes          pull  
100     2        yes          weld  
100     3        no           grind    
100     4        no           machine  
100     5        no           asmbl
```

So I want to select the min(opseq) where opcomplete=no and the max(opseq) where opcomplete=yes, as well as the opcode of the min and max opseq's.  In this example that would be:
min(opseq):3
opcode of min op: grind
max(opseq): 2 
opcode of max op: weld

The reason I am looking for this is to get the opcode of the smallest opseq that is NOT complete.
I got the min and max opseqs to work great.  This is what I had:

```
(SELECT   company, jobnum, MAX(oprseq) AS maxclosed, opcomplete
 FROM     joboper AS joboper_2
 WHERE    (company = 'lot') AND (opcomplete = '1')
 GROUP BY company, jobnum, opcomplete) AS t_joboper1 ON joboper.company = t_joboper1.company AND joboper.jobnum = t_joboper1.jobnum INNER JOIN
(SELECT   company, jobnum, MIN(oprseq) AS minopen, opcomplete
 FROM     joboper AS joboper_1
 WHERE    (company = 'lot') AND (opcomplete = '0')
 GROUP BY company, jobnum, opcomplete) AS t_joboper2 ON joboper.company = t_joboper2.company AND joboper.jobnum = t_joboper2.jobnum
```

So when I tried to get my opcodes added in, it didn't work, and I started gettings all kinds of duplicate values.  This is what I wrote:

```
(SELECT   company, jobnum, MAX(oprseq) AS maxclosed, opcomplete, opcode as maxopcode
 FROM     joboper AS joboper_2
 WHERE    (company = 'lot') AND (opcomplete = '1')
 GROUP BY company, jobnum, opcomplete, opcode) AS t_joboper1 ON joboper.company = t_joboper1.company AND joboper.jobnum = t_joboper1.jobnum INNER JOIN
(SELECT   company, jobnum, MIN(oprseq) AS minopen, opcomplete, opcode as minopcode
 FROM     joboper AS joboper_1
 WHERE    (company = 'lot') AND (opcomplete = '0')
 GROUP BY company, jobnum, opcomplete, opcode) AS t_joboper2 ON joboper.company = t_joboper2.company AND joboper.jobnum = t_joboper2.jobnum
```

Here is my entire code as it stands at the moment (with the opcodes pulling in all the duplicate values:

```
SELECT     jobhead.company, jobhead.jobnum, jobhead.partnum, 
           jobhead.partdescription, jobhead.startdate, 
           jobhead.reqduedate, jobhead.prodqty, jobhead.qtycompleted,
           joboper.oprseq, joboper.opcode, joboper.opcomplete, 
           joboper.qtycompleted AS joboperqtycomplete, 
           resourcegroup.description AS rgroupdescription,
           dmrhead.dmrnum, poheader.ponum, vendor.name AS vendorname,
           t_joboper2.minopen AS minopen, t_joboper2.minopcode AS minopcode,
           t_joboper1.maxclosed AS maxclosed, t_joboper1.maxopcode AS maxopcode
FROM       jobhead LEFT OUTER JOIN
           joboper INNER JOIN
           (SELECT   company, jobnum, MAX(oprseq) AS maxclosed, 
                     opcomplete, opcode as maxopcode
            FROM     joboper AS joboper_2
            WHERE    (company = 'lot') AND (opcomplete = '1')
            GROUP BY company, jobnum, opcomplete, opcode) AS t_joboper1 
              ON     joboper.company = t_joboper1.company 
            AND      joboper.jobnum = t_joboper1.jobnum INNER JOIN
           (SELECT   company, jobnum, MIN(oprseq) AS minopen, opcomplete, 
                     opcode as minopcode
            FROM     joboper AS joboper_1
            WHERE    (company = 'lot') AND (opcomplete = '0')
            GROUP BY company, jobnum, opcomplete, opcode) AS t_joboper2 
              ON     joboper.company = t_joboper2.company
            AND      joboper.jobnum = t_joboper2.jobnum 
              ON     jobhead.company = joboper.company
            AND      jobhead.jobnum = joboper.jobnum LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     resourcegroup ON joboper.company = resourcegroup.company
            AND      joboper.opcode = resourcegroup.opcode LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     dmrhead ON joboper.company = dmrhead.company
            AND      joboper.jobnum = dmrhead.jobnum
            AND      joboper.assemblyseq = dmrhead.assemblyseq 
            AND      joboper.oprseq = dmrhead.oprseq LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     porel ON joboper.company = porel.company
            AND      joboper.jobnum = porel.jobnum
            AND      joboper.assemblyseq = porel.assemblyseq
            AND      joboper.oprseq = porel.jobseq LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     podetail ON porel.company = podetail.company
            AND      porel.ponum = podetail.ponum 
            AND      porel.poline = podetail.poline LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     poheader ON podetail.company = poheader.company 
            AND      podetail.ponum = poheader.ponum LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     vendor ON poheader.company = vendor.company
            AND      poheader.vendornum = vendor.vendornum  
WHERE     (jobhead.jobreleased = 1)
 AND      (jobhead.jobcomplete = 0) 
 AND      (jobhead.company = 'lot') 
 AND      (jobhead.plant = '001')
```

I hope this all makes sense what I am trying to do here.  If it isn't completely obvious this is my first time asking a question on here.  In advance I appreciate all the help!!!

New - 12-21-12

Thank you both for your help!  I tried both of your suggestions, but couldn't get either one to get the exact results I wanted. But each answer helped me get to what it eventually took to get what I needed.  Since this is my first question, I don't know what I should do as far as marking which answer as a solution? Like I said, both answers helped me out a lot, and I think that the reason I couldn't get the results I wanted out of them is soley my fault. After working on this more, I realized that even though I tried very hard to be clear in my question, as I go back I see how I could have worded things much better. Again, I appreciate all the help very much, and I look forward to asking better questions in the future!
By the way, this is the code that worked in the end.

```
 SELECT     jobhead.company, jobhead.jobnum, jobhead.partnum, jobhead.partdescription, jobhead.startdate, jobhead.reqduedate, jobhead.prodqty, jobhead.qtycompleted, 
                  joboper.oprseq, joboper.opcode, joboper.opcomplete, joboper.qtycompleted AS joboperqtycomplete, resourcegroup.description AS rgroupdescription, 
                  dmrhead.dmrnum, poheader.ponum, vendor.name AS vendorname, t_joboper2.minopen, t_joboper1.maxclosed, t_joboper3.opcode AS minopcode
FROM         jobhead LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  joboper INNER JOIN
                      (SELECT     company, jobnum, MAX(oprseq) AS maxclosed, opcomplete
                        FROM          joboper AS joboper_1
                        WHERE      (company = 'lot') AND (opcomplete = '1')
                        GROUP BY company, jobnum, opcomplete) AS t_joboper1 ON joboper.company = t_joboper1.company AND joboper.jobnum = t_joboper1.jobnum INNER JOIN
                      (SELECT     company, jobnum, MIN(oprseq) AS minopen, opcomplete
                        FROM          joboper AS joboper_2
                        WHERE      (company = 'lot') AND (opcomplete = '0')
                        GROUP BY company, jobnum, opcomplete) AS t_joboper2 ON joboper.company = t_joboper2.company AND 
                  joboper.jobnum = t_joboper2.jobnum INNER JOIN
                      (SELECT     company, jobnum, oprseq, opcomplete, opcode
                        FROM          joboper AS joboper_3
                        WHERE      (company = 'lot') AND (opcomplete = '0'))
                         AS t_joboper3 ON t_joboper2.company = t_joboper3.company AND t_joboper2.jobnum = t_joboper3.jobnum AND 
                  t_joboper2.minopen = t_joboper3.oprseq ON jobhead.company = joboper.company AND jobhead.jobnum = joboper.jobnum LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  resourcegroup ON joboper.company = resourcegroup.company AND joboper.opcode = resourcegroup.opcode LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  dmrhead ON joboper.company = dmrhead.company AND joboper.jobnum = dmrhead.jobnum AND joboper.assemblyseq = dmrhead.assemblyseq AND 
                  joboper.oprseq = dmrhead.oprseq LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  porel ON joboper.company = porel.company AND joboper.jobnum = porel.jobnum AND joboper.assemblyseq = porel.assemblyseq AND 
                  joboper.oprseq = porel.jobseq LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  podetail ON porel.company = podetail.company AND porel.ponum = podetail.ponum AND porel.poline = podetail.poline LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  poheader ON podetail.company = poheader.company AND podetail.ponum = poheader.ponum LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  vendor ON poheader.company = vendor.company AND poheader.vendornum = vendor.vendornum
WHERE     (jobhead.jobreleased = 1) AND (jobhead.jobcomplete = 0) AND (jobhead.company = 'lot') AND (jobhead.plant = '001')
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is one approach:

```
select JOB,
       min(case when OPCOMPLETE = 'no' then OPSEQ end) as MIN_NO_OPSEQ,
       min(case when OPCOMPLETE = 'no' then OPCODE end) as MIN_NO_OPCODE,
       min(case when OPCOMPLETE = 'yes' then OPSEQ end) as MAX_YES_OPSEQ,
       min(case when OPCOMPLETE = 'yes' then OPCODE end) as MAX_YES_OPCODE
  from ( select JOB,
                OPSEQ,
                OPCOMPLETE,
                OPCODE,
                rank() over (partition by JOB, OPCOMPLETE order by OPSEQ asc) as R_NO,
                rank() over (partition by JOB, OPCOMPLETE order by OPSEQ desc) as R_YES
           from TABLE_NAME
       )
 where OPCOMPLETE = 'no' and R_NO = 1    -- row with min(OPSEQ) where OPCOMPLETE = 'no'
    or OPCOMPLETE = 'yes' and R_YES = 1  -- row with max(OPSEQ) where OPCOMPLETE = 'yes'
 group
    by JOB
;
```

Notes:

- not tested.
- in lines 2–5, each `min` can be changed to `max` with no effect, since only one row will meet all the necessary criteria. The `min` (or `max`) is only necessary because of the `group by`: we're combining two rows into one by selecting the non-null value.
- for information on `rank()`, see [its documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a lot easier than you are making it, as long as OPSEQ is a unique value:

```
select
    opseq, opcode
from
    joboper
where
    opseq in (select min(opseq) from joboper where opcomplete = 'no')
    or
    opseq in (select max(opseq) from joboper where opcomplete = 'yes')
```

Comment: Perhaps you meant to add grouping by `job` to each of the subqueries.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using SQL Server 2005 or later, you could also consider using [`CROSS APPLY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156.aspx), like this:

```
SELECT
  j.JOB,
  y.OPSEQ  AS LastCompleteOPSEQ,
  y.OPCODE AS LastCompleteOPCODE,
  n.OPSEQ  AS FirstIncompleteOPSEQ,
  n.OPCODE AS FirstIncompleteOPCODE
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT JOB FROM joboper) j
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT TOP 1 OPSEQ, OPCODE
  FROM joboper
  WHERE JOB = j.JOB AND OPCOMPLETE = 'yes'
  ORDER BY OPSEQ DESC
) y
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT TOP 1 OPSEQ, OPCODE
  FROM joboper
  WHERE JOB = j.JOB AND OPCOMPLETE = 'no'
  ORDER BY OPSEQ ASC
) n
;
```

You can this query it [at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8ed69/1).